Debugging a Kelvin Water Dropper
For a high school project, I have to build a Leyden jar, ideally functional...
So to charge it, I'm trying to build a Kelvin Water Dropper. After 2 weeks of trying, and it being due on Monday, I can only come on here and hope some bright minds can help me troubleshoot it .
Here is the annoying machine :

I'll just detail certain parts that I'm sure you're going to comment about !

The inductors aren't touching the wood, there's some insulating foam (about $7mm$ in width once squished)
The water stream breaks into droplets at about half of the inductor
The jars in the bottom are glass, so insulating, and inside there are some copper coils.
The 2 opposite-charge wires are fairly spaced (about $3cm$)

And when the water is flowing, no charge builds up, as the electroscope (the jar at the front of the photo), doesn't show any evidence whatsoever of charge on that system...
The electroscope works, attaching a coil to it and waving a previously-rubbed piece of polystyrene does make the aluminium flaps repel.
Also, I read humidity could be a problem, so I gave one system a little initial "boost" using the piece of polystyrene, to attract certain ions (not quite sure about the charge of polystyrene...).
I've tried using the electroscope and this charged polystyrene in a "circuit" to see if charges were leaving.
I found out :

if I wave the polystyrene on the coil attached directly to the electroscope, it works
if I wave the polystyrene next to the inductor connected to the electroscope, but not the empty containers, it works, but only if the electroscope coil isn't connected (I'm guessing the coil is doing the opposite job, giving up its charges to the air)
if I do wave the polystyrene in any of those 2 positions, but with the coil-activated containers connected, nothing happens (again, probably because the coil is inducing the air)
the 3rd test doesn't work either if the containers are full of regular (so, non-ionized) water

Do you have any ideas what I could be missing ?
The YouTube videos about this machine seem so simple, and yet, I'm still spending too much time on this thing...

Replace the glass drop-catcher jars with metal cans and make contact with them using clamp clips. then connect the leyden jar to one of the two catcher cans- not to the inductor can.
Debugging proceeds as follows:
disconnect the leyden jar and rig up a spark gap instead between the two catcher cans, with a gap of about one millimeter. If the system is operating properly it will begin to shoot a series of sparks across the gap while the water is dripping.

Alright, thanks, I'll try that.
Am I correct saying that the coils are just letting go of the charges ?
The extra jar separate wasn't the Leyden jar, but the electroscope I was talking about in the question.

I do not know! -NN
